# ubuntu12.04 netcdf compile error gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install netcdf (pgi vervion) in the Ubuntu-12.04 with gcc-4.6. However, when I configure  `./configure FC=pgf90 CC=gcc CXX=g++ --prefix=$HOME/netcdf-pgi`, the errors show this:

```
configure:3986: $? = 0
configure:3993: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
configure:3997: $? = 0
configure:4004: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile netcdf with the PGI (Portland group) compilers, then you should use those tools: 
PGF77 , PGFORTRAN , PGC++  and PGCC

In this link is a guide to build and install it correctly. [Portland Group NETCDF 4.11 Build guide](https://www.pgroup.com/resources/netcdf/netcdf411_pgi2011.htm)